How to pass a variable from 1 ViewModel to another?
I have a data grid with fetched info about cryptocurrencies on the main page. User clicks on the desired coin to view detailed info about it. He gets navigated to the currency details page and here is the main problem. I was passing selected currency to CurrencyDetailsPageViewModel like this:
private void OnCurrencyClick(object selectedCurrency)
        {
            var currency = (Currency)selectedCurrency;

            var detailsViewModel = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CurrencyDetailsPageViewModel>();

            detailsViewModel.Currency = currency;

            var detailsPage = new CurrencyDetailsPage(detailsViewModel);
    
            detailsPage.DataContext = detailsViewModel;

            _navigationService.NavigateTo(detailsPage);
        }

And then I need Markets variable on the CurrencyDetailsPageViewModel to be initialized according to the selected currency:
public class CurrencyDetailsPageViewModel
{
    public IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; set; }
    public INavigationService _navigationProvider { get; set; }
    public ICryptocurrencyService _cryptocurrencyService { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public List<Market> Markets { get; set; }

    public CurrencyDetailsPageViewModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, INavigationService navigationService, ICryptocurrencyService cryptocurrencyService)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _navigationProvider = navigationService;
        _cryptocurrencyService = cryptocurrencyService;
        Markets = _cryptocurrencyService.GetTopMarketsAsync(Currency.Id).Result;
    }

    
}

But the problem is that this ViewModel isn't fully initialized so it can initialize the Markets field and I don't know how to handle it properly

Storing a view model in the servicecollection is a very strange thing to do.  I would pass the viewmodel via the constructor, or a property of a view/form.

Sync "state"; i.e. the model; not separate "views".
